# Custom BST deletion (C++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a custom BST which stores data in leaves and each node represents its subtree's smallest value. The left nodes store the higher values and the right nodes store the lower values.

I then delete the data by deleting the leaves and updating the internal nodes, but somehow my deletion could not work.

Here is my code, hope you can point out something wrong with it. Thank you very much.

```
inline BstNode* BstDelete(BstNode* root, rectangle del){
if (root == NULL) return root;
else if (del > root->data){
    root->left = BstDelete(root->left,del);
    if(root->left == NULL) root->data = root->right->data;
    root->data = root->left->data;
}
else if(del < root->data){
    root->right = BstDelete(root->right,del);
    if (root->right == NULL) root->data = root->left->data;
    root->data = root->right->data;
}
else {
    //found
    //Case1: No Child
    if (root -> left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
    //One child
    else if (root->left == NULL){
        root->right = BstDelete(root->right, del);
        if(root->right ==NULL) root = root->right;
        else root->data = root->right->data;
    }
    else if (root->right == NULL){
        root->left = BstDelete(root->left,del);
        if(root->left == NULL) root = root->left;
        else root->data = root->left->data;
    }
    // 2 children
    else {
        root->right = BstDelete(root->right, del);
        if (root->right == NULL) root->data = root->left->data;
        else root->data = root->right->data;

    }
}
return root;}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: 1) Post an [mcve].  2) It is hard to fathom how you can write all of this code, and have the confidence that nothing can go wrong.  You need to learn to use the debugger, since it is near impossible to write code like this and expect it to work the first time.